is there any way I can save a mnt namespace?
like "ip netns add", it mount file "/proc/*/ns/net" somewhere else, when need use the net namespace you can use the mounted file, but when mount --bind a mnt namespace file it report this
# mount --bind /proc/5656/ns/mnt test
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /proc/5656/ns/mnt,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

is there any way I can mount the /proc/*/ns/mnt file or some other way to save the mnt namespace
solution
after post this question, I found this question bind mounts get removed with network namespaces? , it help me come up with a solution
#  mkdir /run/mntns \
        && mount --bind --make-private /run/mntns /run/mntns
# touch /run/mntns/persistent-namespace \
        && mount --bind /proc/5656/ns/mnt /run/mntns/persistent-namespace

the mount success and i can use the mnt namespace by the file "/run/mntns/persistent-namespace".
but there is still some thing I dont understand：

why does it works after "mount --bind --make-private";
why can't I mount bind pid 1 (/usr/lib/systemd/systemd);


You have a typo I think, shouldn't it be mount --bind /proc/5656/ns/net test (note net in place of mnt)?

Make sure test is actually a file. For mount namespaces, /proc/<PID>/ns/mnt is a file, so the target for bind mounting must be a file too.

it‘s not a typo, i am try to save the mnt namespace not net namespace; test is actually a file, it's create by touch test
